# Why does Spark NOT create partitions based on Parquet block size on read? (Instead it appears to partition by Parquet file compressed size)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have the following scenario where I read a Parquet file using Spark:

Number of parquet files: 1

Number of blocks (row group) within the file: 3

Size of each block (row group) as below:

```
blockSize: 195 MB, rowCount: 1395661, compressedSize: 36107 bytes
blockSize: 295 MB, rowCount: 1538519, compressedSize: 38819 bytes
blockSize: 13 MB, rowCount: 52945, compressedSize: 1973 bytes
```

When I try to read this single Parquet file using Spark, it creates only one partition. Below is the code:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet(path)
println(df.rdd.getNumPartitions) // result is 1
```

parquet.block.size = 128 MB

Per my understanding, Hadoop maps one HDFS block to one Parquet block size during read operation and so per this example, it should be mapped to three HDFS blocks. When I try to read this Parquet file using Spark, i was expecting 3 partitions but it resulted in 1 partition and i guess Spark is creating number of partitions based on Parquet file size (which is compressed size) and NOT based on block size within the file.

Question is, why does Spark NOT partition data based on number of blocks/block sizes within a Parquet file and instead it appears to partition by Parquet file size (compressed size)?

Comment: S3, AZURE Blob or bare metal or AWS EC2 environment?

Comment: Have a look at this https://animeshtrivedi.github.io/spark-parquet-reading and note that parquet is a columnar format.

Comment: Source is HDFS.. Yes, parquet is columnar format and hence I expect spark to create partitions based on block size within parquet file format.. https://www.dremio.com/tuning-parquet

Answer (score 1):

> The size of a partition in Spark is dictated by spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes . The default is 128 MB.

Damji, Jules S.,Wenig, Brooke,Das, Tathagata,Lee, Denny. Learning Spark (pp. 264-265). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

Note that, a corollary of the above quote is that the partitioning of a Spark Dataframe is independent of the layout of the file that the Dataframe is created from.

As you only have one partition after read, it looks like you have a value set for `maxPartitionBytes` that is larger than the file you are reading.

Comment: Number of core allocated to my application is 8.. HDFS is my source. By default, Spark creates one partition for each block of the file (blocks being 128MB by default in HDFS) https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html. In case of parquet, the file sizes are compressed one and hence i expected spark to create partitions based on block sizes inside the file.. In my scenario, the parquet file has 3 blocks inside and each is of 128MB size and hence anticipating 3 partitions  by spark..

Comment: This is long time question I always have... Does spark create partitions based on file block size or cluster configuration?.. For example, in my local laptop, I have 8 cores, but if I give input as 20 files(each less than 128MB) for spark to read, it creates 20 partitions.. Per my understanding and experience, Spark default partitions is always by file characteristics(128MB) and hence in case of shuffle, default partitions is 200...Please let me know if you have explanation on this or could direct me to the spark library code which does partitioning based on cluster size..

Comment: The link you shared does indeed explain that when using the textFile method, Spark creates a partition for each block of the file, but you are not using that method.

Comment: So you can't expect each HDFS block to map to a partition when reading parquet files.

Comment: I did not use textFile.method. I have used spark.read.parquet(path).. I had 20 parquet files in the input directory and when i read it using spark, it created 20 partitions.. my core size is only 4.. I always see spark creates partitions based on file characteristics and it is up to the user to override with optimal partition number based on cluster size(using repartition, coalesce).. I generally choose number of partitions to be 3 * number of cores available..